# "PHP Fileinfo extension must be installed/enabled to use Intervention Image." error

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I'm getting this error `"PHP Fileinfo extension must be installed/enabled to use Intervention Image."` when I try out the Laravel example:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $img = Image::make('foo.jpg')->resize(300, 200);

    return $img->response('jpg');
});
```

I've uncommented `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` in the php.ini file located in `C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.1.5` but that doesn't work. I restarted my PC and my MAMP after doing this. I'm hosting my website myself.

Comment: are you sure you edited the correct ini file? what does phpinfo() give you in the loaded ini files section?

Comment: Also, Isn't MAMP for Mac? Why is it on a Windows C drive?

Comment: C:\MAMP\conf\php7.1.5\php.ini

Comment: phpinfo(); is it enabled?!

Comment: You said you edited a file in the `bin` folder, not the `conf`

Comment: Yes, I didn't know there was another php.ini file. After adding "extension=php_fileinfo.dll" to the new php.ini, everything is working fine. Thank you.

Comment: cheers, if i add that as an answer can you accept it?

Comment: Yes, do that :) .

Comment: cheers! have a nice day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have edited the wrong ini file.

Check the loaded ini files section of `phpinfo()`.

> UPDATE you edited an ini in the `bin` folder and not the `conf`. Editing the one in conf should fix your issue.